# registering new user when authenticated in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, redirect, user-registration

i have classified my users table to have role in it
Admin
Student
Teacher

as an admin i can register  new student/teacher.
but when im authenticated as an admin, the register button went straight to home.

the problem  is i can register new account when i am a guest.

i have tried to change RedirectIfAuthenticated.php to /register
[image]

but i got this error;

it said  i got too many error
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are getting redirected too many times to the same page because of the IF statement that you have. You are checking if it's true. You need to redirect to the `/register` route only if It's false. With others words you need

```
if (! Auth::guard($guard)->check()) { 
    //your redirect here 
}
```